# how to insert date & time to DateTimePicker in C#?

Tags: c#

i want to insert date & time to DateTimePicker.

for example: date: 03/08/2009  time: 06:45

how i can do it in C# ?

thank's in advance

Comment: you just set it, what is the problem that you encountered ?
Is it winforms or wpf ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something along this line

```
myDatePicker.Value = new DateTime(2009, 3, 8, 6, 45, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new DateTime with the value you want and set the .Value property of the DateTimePicker to it.

```
dtp.Value = new DateTime( 2009, 3, 8, 6, 45, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

just want to add, you may also use a string and pass it to the [**DateTime.Parse**](http://dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse) method which will return `DataTime` object as follows, if you have `string` value representing DateTime in proper format.

So you can avoid splitting your string into values, as `Year`, `Day` or `Month` etc and thereafter passing these values to DateTime `Constructor`.

---

Here is how you do it:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse("03/08/2009 06:45:00");
```